# Set test message limitation in Test Teardown of Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

```
*** Settings ***

Test Teardown      My Teardown Keyword

*** Keywords ***
My Teardown Keyword
    Function 1
    Set test message  ${my message here}
    Function 2
```

Set test message prints whatever you want on message column in report.html. The thing is, if my Test Teardown fails, the error message overwrites the ${TEST MESSAGE} global variable being used by Set test message so whatever its previous contents are, it won't be displayed on the report.html message column, only the error message.

Is there a workaround I can do here to still print the original contents of the ${TEST MESSAGE} variable even if Test Teardown fails?

Comment: Maybe simply use another variable for the message? Or list of messages, to keep all messages without losing anything.

Comment: But in order to print them on message column. The robot KW Set Test Message is necessary to print them on report.html and that keyword stores the message on ${TEST MESSAGE} global variable